# Яндекс карты в слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Подскажите, как вставить яндекс карты в слайдер, а то такой вариант не работает

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="carousel" id="carousel-952539">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=GWk7QNN6JCLTuJT5csJ8EID7NpBk_zKq&width=100%&height=100%&lang=ru_RU&sourceType=constructor"></script>
                </div>
                <div class="item active">
                    <img alt="Carousel Bootstrap Third" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-1600-500-3.jpg">
                </div>
            </div> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-952539" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"><img src="images/arrow-left.png"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-952539" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><img src="images/arrow-right.png"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

хех , а слайдеру самому ширину - высоту задать не про бывали ?  http://jsfiddle.net/aqoq8noq/

```
<div class="item active" style='width:500px;height:500px;'>
```

У Вас он просто схлопывается , так как нет width-height;